# “non response” or “non-responders” or simply “no response”!

Tags: expressions

I read this a lot in published medical articles: 
“Patients without a favorable response to treatment were identified as patients with non response (NR).”
Shouldn’t it be written “patients with no reaponse (NR)” instead?
It seems to me that “non response” is often used incorrectly.

Comment: Please cite your sources.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form is "non response" meaning:

a refusal or failure to respond : lack of response  (Merriam Webster)

as in:

nonresponse to medical treatment

Answer (score 0):

I can see why it bothers you.  I'll show it to you in a slightly different way, to make it more palatable for you:

> Patients without a favorable response to treatment were identified as patients with "non response" (NR).

A better written sentence would be:

> Patients without a favorable response to treatment were labeled as "non response" (NR).

I imagine it came from wanting to use a uniform pattern of the type *low response, high response, favorable response, unfavorable response*.  "Complete lack of response" would have been too wordy.

Answer (score -1):

[This statement](https://books.google.co.in/books?isbn=1481620266)

> Sustained **virological response** (SVR) was achieved in 46% of the 164 included patients, 29% had a **non-response** (NR) and 25% had **relapse** (RR). (emphasis mine.)

shows that the term refers to the type of response by the patient, not the type of patient. It is customary to classify patients according to the type of response.

HTH.